# Getting garbage values when transfering file from server to client in c?

Tags: c

this is my c code of the server and the client.
/*  TCP server */

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>

        #include <stdlib.h>

            FILE *fp;

        int main(int argc, char**argv){


            int listenfd,connfd,n;


            struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
            socklen_t clilen;

            char * banner = "1077"; // size of the file
            char buffer[1000];


            /* one socket is dedicated to listening */

            listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

            /* initialize a sockaddr_in struct with our own address information for
            binding the socket */

            servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

            /* binding */
            bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
            listen(listenfd,0); //listen( --,--);
            clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);

            /* accept the client with a different socket. */
            connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen); // the uninitialized cliaddr variable is filled in with the
            n = recvfrom(connfd,buffer,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);//information of the client by recvfrom function
                buffer[n] = 0;
            sendto(connfd,banner,strlen(banner),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
            printf("Received:%s\n",buffer);


             char file_name[] ="severtext.txt";




                 fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

                           if( fp == NULL )
                           {
                              perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
                              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                           }

                printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);
            char sendData[1000];
        /*open servertext.txt and coppy it to a char array */
                fread(sendData, 1000, 1, fp);

                printf("The contents of sending\n");

                         sendto(connfd,sendData,sizeof(sendData),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));

        /*information of the client by recvfrom function */
                         n = recvfrom(connfd,buffer,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
                         buffer[n] = 0;
                         printf("Received:%s\n",buffer);









                 printf("End of connection \n");


            return 0;
        }
```

...client code
    /* Sample TCP client */

```
 #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>



    int main(int argc, char**argv){



            int sockfd,n;
            FILE *fp;
            fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
        char banner[] = "request serverfile.txt";

           char revbuf1[1000];

        char buffer[4];

        if (argc != 2){
            printf("usage: ./%s <IP address>\n",argv[0]);
            return -1;
        }
        /* socket to connect */
        sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        /* IP address information of the server to connect to */
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
        servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);
        connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

        sendto(sockfd,banner,strlen(banner),0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

        n=recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,10,0,NULL,NULL);
        buffer[n]=0;

        printf("Received: %s\n",buffer);


            printf("[Client] Receiveing file from Server and saving it as final.txt...");
            char * banner1="ok";


            printf("\ndata1 set\n"); 

            n=recvfrom(sockfd,revbuf1,1000,0,NULL,NULL);
        revbuf1[n]=0;
            sendto(sockfd,banner1,strlen(banner1),0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
        printf("Received: %s\n",revbuf1);
            //open file.txt and over write it with the recieved data in the client side.
            fwrite(revbuf1, 1000, 1, fp);
            fclose(fp);


             close (sockfd);
             printf("[Client] Connection lost.\n");
        return 0;


    }
```

When i run these two programs i get garbage values in the file.txt with the servertext.txt content, Can someone help to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you seeing the correct data received on the client in the `stdio` output from your `printf` statements?

Comment: Hint for code formatting: (1) Edit the code in your favorite editor. (2) Copy the well formatted (and indented) code to clipboard. (3) Paste to the StackOverflow text input control. (4) Mark the code in the text input. (5) Click on the `{}` symbol above the entry area. That's all, each click is documented. It's easy. (period)  BTW: This way you post code that might have seen a compiler.

Comment: When you have code which doesn't quite work, first add error checking to all system calls (and even if you have code which works for you when you test it in a particular environment, *still* add error checking, but that's beside the point here). `perror` is your friend.

Comment: I got the correct data on the cmd. But at the end there were some garbage values other than the file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are writing the whole of the rxd string to the file with

```
fwrite(revbuf1, 1000, 1, fp);
```

and any unused space in the array will be garbage. You should do this:

```
fwrite(revbuf1, 1, n, fp);
```